# php check if gravatar exists header error

Tags: php, header, gravatar

I'm trying to check if a gravatar exists.  When I try the approach recommended in earlier questions, I get an error " Warning: get_headers() [function.get-headers]: This function may only be used against URLs"  Anyone seen this or see the error in my code?  PS I do not want to specify a default image for gravatar to serve as there could be more than one default possibilities if no gravatar exits.

Also, I found a reference to error possibly being related to my ini file which I don't think my host gives me access to.  If so, is there an alternative to getheaders?  Many thanks.

```
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$email= "person@gmail.com"; //for testing
$gravemail = md5( strtolower( trim( $email ) ) );
$gravsrc = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/".$gravemail;
$gravcheck = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/".$gravemail."?d=404";
$response = get_headers('$gravcheck');
echo $response;
exit;
if ($response != "404 Not Found"..or whatever based on response above){
$img = $gravsrc;
}
```

Comment: Loose the apostrophes around $gravcheck, otherwise it's just a string containing "$gravcheck" and not the variable's content: `get_headers($gravcheck);`

Comment: Many thanks for this catch..it was causing the error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Observation

A. `get_headers('$gravcheck');` would not work because of use of single quote `'`

B. calling `exit;` would terminate script prematurely

C. `$response` would return an array you can not use `echo` to print the information use `print_r` insted

D. `$response != "404 Not Found"` would not work because `$response` is array

This is the proper way to do it :

```
$email= "person@gmail.com"; //for testing
$gravemail = md5( strtolower( trim( $email ) ) );
$gravsrc = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/".$gravemail;
$gravcheck = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/".$gravemail."?d=404";
$response = get_headers($gravcheck);
print_r($response);
if ($response[0] != "HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"){
    $img = $gravsrc;
}
```

Comment: The first response index now contains the string "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found". I would personally use `strpos($response[0], "404 Not Found") === false` to determine whether or not the header response is valid, but overall, this is a very nice way of explicitly checking for a 404.

Comment: Cool but;
must be
".......
 if ($response[0] ......"

`
$email= "test@youremaildomain.com"; //for testing
   $gravemail = md5( strtolower( trim( $email ) ) );
   $gravsrc = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/".$gravemail;
   $gravcheck = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/".$gravemail."?d=404";
   $response = get_headers($gravcheck);
  
   if ($response[0] == "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"){
    $grv_check = true;
   } else {
    $grv_check = false;
   }`

Answer (score 0):

While doing my one of a project, I had made a simple function of Gravatar in php.

You can see it.

```
  <?php

  class GravatarHelper
  {

    /**
    * validate_gravatar
    *
    * Check if the email has any gravatar image or not
    *
    * @param  string $email Email of the User
    * @return boolean true, if there is an image. false otherwise
    */
    public static function validate_gravatar($email) {
      $hash = md5($email);
      $uri = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' . $hash . '?d=404';
      $headers = @get_headers($uri);
      if (!preg_match("|200|", $headers[0])) {
        $has_valid_avatar = FALSE;
      } else {
        $has_valid_avatar = TRUE;
      }
      return $has_valid_avatar;
    }



    /**
    * gravatar_image
    *
    *  Get the Gravatar Image From An Email address
    *
    * @param  string $email User Email
    * @param  integer $size  size of image
    * @param  string $d     type of image if not gravatar image
    * @return string        gravatar image URL
    */
    public static function gravatar_image($email, $size=0, $d="") {
      $hash = md5($email);
      $image_url = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' . $hash. '?s='.$size.'&d='.$d;
      return $image_url;
    }

  }
```

In here, there are two functions.

1. `validate_gravatar()` will return true or false based on if the email has any gravatar or not.
2. `gravatar_image()` will return the gravatar image url for your email

Hope it will help to others.